# Increasing, continuous function implies connectivity and viceversa.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am having difficulties showing that this is true. How would you prove this statement?

Given that the function $h: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is increasing. Show that $h$ is continuous if and only if  $h(\mathbb{R})$ is connected.

Answer (score 2):

If $g$ is continuous then $g(\mathbb{R})$ is connected by the intermediate value theorem.

If $g$ is not continuous, then it must have a jump discontinuity (this is the only type of discontinuity an increasing function can have) so $g(\mathbb{R})$ is not connected.

To show that $g$ can only have jump discontinuities, it's enough to show that $\lim_{x\to x_0^{-}}g(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to x_0^{+}}g(x)$ exist for all $x_0$, which is a consequence of the fact that $g$ is increasing.

Comment: I understand it, but how would you prove it rigorously for both parts (if and only if)?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: The part where if it is connected, then h is continuous. Also, how would you show the side limits using an epsilon proof?

Comment: You can prove that connected implies continuous by using the contrapositive, as I did in my answer. To prove that $\lim_{x\to x_0^{-}}g(x)$ exists, note that the set $\{g(x):x<x_0\}$ is bounded above by $g(x_0)$, hence has a supremum $L$. Then you should be able to prove that $L=\lim_{x\to x_0^{-}}g(x)$ using properties of suprema, together with the fact that $g$ is increasing.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense. Thanks!