# Assume h is an increasing function from the set of real numbers to the set of reals. Show h(R) connected implies that h is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Assume h is an increasing function from the set of real numbers to the set of reals. (h: R -> R). Show h(R) connected implies that h is continuous.

Comment: What's wrong with the answer you got to the [question you asked an hour ago](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1729635/increasing-continuous-function-implies-connectivity-and-viceversa)?

Comment: @AlexS I think OP did not notice the proof by transposition used in that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that exist $a\in\mathbb{R}$, a discontinuity point of $h$. Because $h$ is increasing, $h$ have numerable points of discontinuity, exists $\lim_{x\to a^-}h(x)=a'$. Now, $h(a)\geq a'$ because is increasing. If $h(a)=b>a'$, then $h([a,+\infty))\subset [b,+\infty)$ and $h((-\infty,a))\subset (-\infty,a']$.

Put $c=(a'+b)/2$ and $h(\mathbb {R})=U\cup V$ with $U=(-\infty,c)\cap h(\mathbb {R}), V= (c,+\infty)\cap h(\mathbb {R})$ open nonempty sets, and absurd because $ h(\mathbb {R})$ is connected.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense now!